# Machine not communicating to gateway which is a layer 3 switch

Tags: networking

I have created VLAN 400 in a switch, added ports to that VLAN.Connected one interface of that VLAN to a L3 switch and given IP(10.210.2.1/23) to that interface of the L3 switch. Now my problem is that hosts connected to the interface of VLAN 400 cannot communicate to 10.210.2.1(Destination unreachable), however they can communicate with each other. Hosts IP 10.210.2.8/23 and 10.210.2.10/23.Even 10.210.2.1 cannot ping to the hosts.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand, you have such scheme: `PCs -> L3 Switch > Core Switch(GW for PCs)`. PCs could communicate between each other, that mean, there is no problem with L3 Switch. Looks like you have problem on connection between Switch and Core Switch or problems with Core Switch configuration.

Please check connectivity, you could add IP on L3 Switch and try to ping Core Switch from L3 Switch.

Also, you configured on Core Switch IP on interface VLAN 400? If you configure it on line interface, it will not work.

Comment: No the network connections are like this hosts connected to L2 switch(contains VLAN 400) and from that L2 switch (an interface in VLAN 400) is given to L3 switch(10.210.2.1) which is acting as a gateway. Now hosts can ping each other but they cannot ping the gateway. Hosts are also in VLAN 400.Scheme is PCs -> L2 switch(contains VLAN 400) -> L3 switch(10.210.2.1)

Comment: Have you configure VLAN 400 on L3 Switch? If yes, what IP you configured there?

Comment: Yes I configured VLAN 400 on L3 switch. No I haven't configured any IP to VLAN 400 on L3 switch. Interface on L3 switch acting like L3 port with its own IP

Comment: That's the reason, your L2 switch looking for VLAN400 on uplink port, but you have non VLAN port on L3 Switch, you should reconfigure uplonk port and put Gateway IP on VLAN400.

Comment: It still not working.As you said I have configured VLAN 400 on one of the ports of L3 switch connect it to L2 switch and given IP to VLAN 400.on L3 switch but it is still not pinging

Comment: @amit please describe current configuration in start post. It help me to understand your configuration or someone else could help you.

Comment: L2 config  


vlan 400 name cloud  

int range GE 13-20  
switchport mode access  
switchport access vlan 400  
  
  
L3 switch config  
  
vlan 400 name cloud  
int GE 34  
switchport mode access  
switchport access vlan 400  

int vlan 400  
ip address 10.210.2.1 255.255.254.0

Comment: Sorry I am not able to format the text

Comment: @amit, could you show output for command `show int vlan 400` on L3  switch.

Comment: Actually my switch is cisco sg300-52 so command sets are a bit different.I am showing output for sh ip int vlan 400

Comment: `    IP Address         Type     Directed   Precedence   Status    
                                Broadcast                         
------------------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- 
10.210.2.1/23       Static      disable    No         Valid   `

Comment: Sorry I am not able to format text its directed broadcast

Comment: i changed the config a little i created a trunk  between L2 switch and L3 switch allowed VLAN 400 on the trunk(SVI). But it is still not working. I tried the same setup on Cisco packet tracer it's working

Comment: @amit, are you sure, that you doesn't have problems with cable?

Comment: Both switches are autodetect the type of cable so i used straight through cable between switches. Also the light on both the switch ports on both L2 and L3 switches are green.